# Mongo DB query on Mongo DB driver for Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I need to compare two fields on my mongo db database, and this is the query for that

`db.characters.find({$expr:{$eq:["$currentLv", "$maxLv"]}})`

How can i query like this on mongo db driver for golang (mgo)

Answer (score 0):

I won't write about how instantiate connection to mongodb, if you didn't know, [here is the link](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver#usage).

And your query will be something like that:

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
defer cancel()

filter := bson.M{
    "$expr": bson.M{
        "$eq": []string{"$currentLv", "$maxLv"},
    },
}

_, _ = db.Database("dbname").Collection("collection").Find(ctx, filter, options.Find())
```